# Access Photo Library in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, photo-gallery

I am creating a game using cocos2d. 
Now what I want is I need to insert the image from Photo Library to my application. Can you please tell how can we access Photo Library through cocos2d?

Thanks in ADVANCE...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to access the users Photo Library in the normal fashion. As far as actually using the selected photo, is a different question.  `;-)`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you mean but...

To use an image in your application you put the image file in your resources folder in xcode.  Then you can reference it by name to use it for your sprites or anything else that will use a file.  This goes for other types of files that your application will use too (like data files, plists, etc).

If you put an icon file in your resources folder in xcode and name it icon.png then that will be the icon that will appear for the user to select to run your application on the iphone/ipod/ipad.

Same goes if you put another file in the resources folder and name it default.png then it will show up as the splash screen that appears while your application is being loaded.

Note: If you are working with a template it will probably already have canned files with these names. Just remove them from the resource folder in xcode and add the new ones. To add the files to your project, drag them into the resource folder within xcode and select the check box for: "Copy items into destination group's folder (if needed)", as well as, make sure in add targets section only the check box for your application name is checked and the radio button "Recursively create groups for any added folders" is selected. This will copy the file(s) into your project directory and they will also appear in the resources folder in xcode. You can then click on them in xcode to see that they are correct.

Comment: The question pertains to accessing a photo from the users Photo Library, a photo in the app bundle is not the same thing. And I have never seen a template that already contained a Default and icon file, unless it it an example project.

Comment: Oh ok sorry I miss understood your question.  I am not familiar with how to access the photo library either.  Regarding the default files in a template: If you make a new cocos2d project, the png files in resources will be created for you with the little cocos2d coconut guy as the images (default.png and icon.png).